# How can I delete .wav metadata without changing any of its features?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, metadata, wav

I have to delete additional info from `.wav` header so it can be processed by another program. After some search I have tried to use `ffmpeg`, for example:

```
ffmpeg -y -i $filename -map_metadata -1 -codec copy $filename
```

or

```
ffmpeg -y -i $filename -map_metadata -1 -c:v copy -c:a copy $filename
```

However, while the new `.wav` file maintains old features, both of them cut the length of my `.wav` files that are longer than 4 seconds, for example 4,9 seconds becomes 4,03 in some cases, and the recorded voice is cut.

What can I use for my purpose? I need new file with same features (16bit, 16000Hz, mono, 256kb/s) but without info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FFmpeg does not edit file in place. Output has to be different.

```
ffmpeg -y -i $filename -map_metadata -1 -codec copy $newfilename
```